# navigationController.viewControllers is 0 after setViewControllers

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

In my appDelegate, I am setting ClassA to be a root view of navigation controller like below

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
  self.window       =   [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  ClassA    *classA =   [[ClassA alloc] initWithNibName:@"ClassA" bundle:nil];

  self.navigationController  =   [[UINavigationController alloc] classA];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

Then at classA, I am doing

```
- (void)myMethod {
  NSMutableArray *navigationArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];    

  NSLog(@"before using setViewControlles---->navigationarray.viewControllers is %d",[navigationArray1 count]);

  ClassB     *classB     =   [[ClassB alloc] initWithNibName:@"ClassB" bundle:nil];
  [self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:classB] animated:YES]; 

  NSMutableArray *navigationarray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
  NSLog(@"after using setViewControllers---->navigationController.viewControllers is %d",[navigationarray2 count]);
```

}

In debug mode, i am getting

```
before using setViewControlles---->navigationarray.viewControllers is 1
after  using setViewControlles---->navigationarray.viewControllers is 0
```

I thought the result should be 1 after using `setViewControllers`

I am getting lost now and needing some advices from you guys. Please help if you have any ideas about this issue. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
self.window.rootViewController = classA
```

I changed my answer. self.navigationController.rootViewController is wrong

Comment: it is not correct, navigationController does not have property named `rootViewController`